# Page.IsPostBack always false after urlRewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a strange problem.

Page.IsPostBack returns always false after url Rewriting.

I am using a link that directs to a function, like,

```
<a href="#" onclick="return getHelp('4','P')">
```

This goes to js file and js calls below pagemethod.

```
<script>
function getHelp(id, type) {
PageMethods.displayHelp(id, type, CallSuccess, CallFailed);
}
</script>
```

This is the pageMethod that i try to access from javascript,

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string displayHelp(string id, string type)
{
 response.writeline(id+type);
}
```

If i don't use urlrewriting it works perfect. However, if i use urlrewriting, the postback could not recognized.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not apparent to me from your code but if you are simply reloading the page via JavaScript, the postback model will be broken.

```
Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()
```

to get a client side postback method.

Comment: I'm trying to access pageMethod via js function. if i use urlrewriting, Page.IsPostBack returns false and it only loads page_load. I've added pagemethod that i try to access also

Comment: To generate a server side postback where IsPostBack is true, you will need to call the client side Postback JavaScript method. Use the server side method that I detailed above to get that code and pass it to your client and then invoke it.